# Github - see quick setup guide

Tags: git, github, installation, repository

When first creating a new repository online on github, you are taken to a quick setup guide in which all major commands are shown, "customized" according to your repository name. Is it possible to show that page again? I was not able to find it anymore... Thank you

Comment: In case you don't get a direct answer, you might want to include your actual question as well.

Comment: Why don't you just create another repo to get the same page?

Comment: That's what i did... I would like to know if there is a smarter way of getting the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the smartest way could be to see git's book

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. The purpose of my question was asking if there was a way to reach "that" exact page again but there seems to be no way.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/ I'm not sure, but maybe this is the content that you saw on that page, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You do not see the quickstart page unless you make ZERO changes up to that point. So you need to be OK with deleting your repo, and starting again from scratch. (Settings - scroll down to "danger area").

When you start again, only choose a name and optional description, **do not click any other options**. Then click the button to create the repo. E.g. do not choose a drop down license first: I did that, and so never saw the "quick start" page. You will only see the "quick start" page if your repo has absolutely no changes or content of any kind (other than its name and brief description).

Comment: resist the "add a README file" option